# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in subreports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, subreports

My report combines two independent reports together. The main report has no data sources, but the two subreports use the same three-table dataset.

How can I resolve this error that I get from running the code below?

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
objRpt = New rptOVERDET
objRpt.SummaryInfo.Dispose()
objRpt.Subreports("srOverview").SetDataSource(dsDetail)
objRpt.Subreports("srOverview").SummaryInfo.Dispose()
objRpt.Subreports("srOverview").SummaryInfo.ReportComments = "Overview Report" & Trim(strReportHeader) & vbNewLine & Trim(strContactPhone)

objRpt.Subreports("srDetail").SetDataSource(dsDetail)
objRpt.Subreports("srDetail").SummaryInfo.Dispose()
objRpt.Subreports("srDetail").SummaryInfo.ReportComments = "Detail Report" & Trim(strReportHeader) & vbNewLine & Trim(strContactPhone)
```

Comment: You still have to set the data source on the main report. You may not need to set the sub report datasets at all. Also, don't make any of those dispose calls until after the report is loaded, and you only do that on the main report.

Comment: No matter how many subreports you have the important is how do you construct your query? see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41810978/query-from-two-tables-in-report/41819099#41819099

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099131/how-can-we-pass-a-parameter-from-main-report-to-subreport-in-crystal-reports-xi

Comment: I am getting the following error
An unhandled exception of type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.DataSourceException' occurred in CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll

Additional information: The report has no tables.

I changed the code to be as follows:

Comment: objRpt = New rptOVERDET

objRpt.SetDataSource(dsDetail)

objRpt.SummaryInfo.Dispose()

                objRpt.Subreports("srOverview").SummaryInfo.ReportComments = "Overview Report" & Trim(strReportHeader) & vbNewLine & Trim(strContactPhone)

Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()

objRpt.Subreports("srDetail").SummaryInfo.ReportComments = "Detail Report" & Trim(strReportHeader) & vbNewLine & Trim(strContactPhone)

Comment: reds, I have the queries working correctly.  These were reports that are currently standalone reports now.  We were combining them so that they could view the overview and detail information as a browse on their computer.