# how config tokens and layouts for crystal report and SAP B1?

Tags: crystal-reports, parameter-passing, hana, invoice, sapb1

I'm trying to use the tokens `DocKey@` for A/R INVOICE layout. I build my report on Crystal Reports 2013 + SQL HANA.

I import the report and set as standard layout but didn't print and in preview request the `DocKey`.

Here my SQL query on Crystal command with the parameter `DocKey@`:

[image: here my sqlquery on crystal command with the parameter DocKey@]

and here when request the parameter:

[image: and here when request the parameter]

Additionally, I'm trying to use `FolioNum@` and `FolioPref@` as parameter. Do I need more parameters? or I forgot some config of the layout to properly work without require the parameters and retrieve them from the Form?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with this  [POST][1]

[1]: [How can we pass a parameter from main report to subreport in crystal reports XI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099131/how-can-we-pass-a-parameter-from-main-report-to-subreport-in-crystal-reports-xi)  , use de SubReport Links help me.