# How to Combine same Parameter Enter Value into one entry parameter in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that has 2 parameters, namely `{?PERIOD}` and `{?TAHUN}`(TAHUN IN ENGLISH IS YEAR). In the report there is a sub report as page 2 which has the same parameters, {?PERIOD} and {?TAHUN}.
Yesterday I edited the `{?TAHUN}` parameter, I added 2023 to the `{?TAHUN}` parameter in the main report and sub report. but after the crystal report is run, the {?TAHUN} parameter between the main report and the sub report becomes separate, 2 separate entry values. how to restore this condition and make `{?TAHUN}` parameter to 1 prompt like `{?PERIOD}` parameter.

This is image when I run in the main report

[image: after]

Before I edit the parameters
[image: before]

Comment: You can edit the subreport parameter links – see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099131/how-can-we-pass-a-parameter-from-main-report-to-subreport-in-crystal-reports-xi for a detailed description.

Comment: Thank you @mweber , Previously the main report and subreport didn't use a link because once the report was run, the parameters were already grouped. like auto grouping without being given a link on sub report. I've also tried adding a link to the subreport but the result is the same.